# Right-aligned constraints for equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I'm looking to write an equation (using gather), with some constraints on the right-hand side.

Ideally, I'd like the equations to be horizontally-aligned with one another (i.e. have centers line-up vertically in a given equation grouping), and the constraints following similar behaviour, but at the right-hand-side of the page, inside the right-margin.

**edit**:The equation alignment should also be consistent with the rest of the document.

The following is an example of (almost) the kind of behaviour I'm looking for, using the `\tag` command, but note that the length of the first tag has moved the first equation, and that the tags are right-aligned as opposed to centred in some abstract column near the right-hand side. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
a^2 + b^2 = ab \tag{$(a \in \{z,y,x,w,v,u\},\ b \neq 0)$}\\
\text{centered fine}\tag{short}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

I'm happy to redefine `\tag` as long as it's not going to affect any of the equation-numbering elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the longest constraint needs to be flushed to the right margin, you could use a `tabular*` environment with two centered columns; something along these lines (change the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength\MyIndent
\setlength\MyIndent{10em}

\begin{document}

\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\MyIndent}}>{$}c<{$}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{$}c<{$}@{}}
  a^2 + b^2 = ab & (a \in \{z,y,x,w,v,u\},\ b \neq 0) \\
  a + b = c & (a \in \{z,y\},\ b = 0) \\
\end{tabular*}\par
\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

\end{document}
```

If the longest constraint doesn't need to be flushed to the right margin, a simple array environment will do the job (change the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{\hspace{7em}}c@{\hspace{3em}}c}
  a^2 + b^2 = ab & (a \in \{z,y,x,w,v,u\},\ b \neq 0) \\
  a + b = c & (a \in \{z,y\},\ b = 0) \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I wanted my equations to look consistent with other equations nearby (horizontal alignment) --- I've edited my question to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't need alignment at relation symbols, but centered alignment, you could use an `array` environment with `c` columns.

I considered putting two `gathered` environments next to each other, however, in contrast to an array, alignment of the baselines would not be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do anything like what you want?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    a^2 + b^2 = ab, & a \in \{z,y,x,w,v,u\},\ b \neq 0 \\
    a + b = 0, & b \neq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

​